# SQL Incremental Value for Existing Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with the below structure in sql server and would like to create an update stored procedure to set the value for seq_num column.

| fname | lname | orderid | seq_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Torrey | Venard | 246 | 376987 |
| Gabey | Tate | 247 | 376988 |
| Germaine | Ferminger | 248 | 376989 |
| Nikita | Sharplin | 249 | 376990 |
| Boyd | Rannigan | 250 | 376991 |
| Claretta | Paoli | 251 | 376992 |
| Barn | Kulver | 252 | 376993 |
| Torrey | Venard | 253 | 376994 |
| Gabey | Tate | 254 | NULL |
| Germaine | Ferminger | 255 | NULL |
| Nikita | Sharplin | 256 | NULL |
| Boyd | Rannigan | 257 | NULL |

The total rows is about 20k. Ideally we should have this column as an auto increment, but what we are looking for is to fill in the NULLs with the next number like below:

| fname | lname | orderid | seq_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Torrey | Venard | 246 | 376987 |
| Gabey | Tate | 247 | 376988 |
| Germaine | Ferminger | 248 | 376989 |
| Nikita | Sharplin | 249 | 376990 |
| Boyd | Rannigan | 250 | 376991 |
| Claretta | Paoli | 251 | 376992 |
| Barn | Kulver | 252 | 376993 |
| Torrey | Venard | 253 | 376994 |
| Gabey | Tate | 254 | 376995 |
| Germaine | Ferminger | 255 | 376996 |
| Nikita | Sharplin | 256 | 376997 |
| Boyd | Rannigan | 257 | 376998 |

any thoughts suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: thanks I added the tag.

Comment: You already know about ROW_NUMBER(). Apply that against all the rows with NULL values and add the resulting row number to the MAX() value in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that column seq_num is int. So you can try with `cursor` as below:

```
DECLARE @Orderid int 

DECLARE Seq_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 

    Select  Orderid from table1 Where seq_num IS NULL  Order by Orderid

    OPEN Seq_CURSOR
    BEGIN TRY
    FETCH NEXT FROM Seq_CURSOR  INTO @Orderid  

    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRAN   
            
           Update table1 set seq_num = (Select Max(seq_num)+1 from table1 )  Where orderId = @Orderid

            FETCH NEXT FROM Seq_CURSOR  INTO @Orderid  
            
            SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF;
            COMMIT TRAN;
                      
        END
        DEALLOCATE Seq_CURSOR;   
    END TRY 

    BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
CLOSE Seq_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE Seq_CURSOR
```